# Can not insert values into SQL Server table from text box control inside a repeater in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a comment box in an ASP.NET website and it is inside a repeater. So I want to add the values of textboxes into a SQL Server table, but it doesn't insert.

There is also no error. I can load comments from database but can not insert comment inside it.

Here is my code for send comment button:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in productrepeat.Items)
{
        TextBox commentname = (TextBox)item.FindControl("commentname") as TextBox;
        TextBox content = (TextBox)item.FindControl("content") as TextBox;
        TextBox email = (TextBox)item.FindControl("email") as TextBox;
        Label sendtext = (Label)item.FindControl("sendtext") as Label;

        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand insertcommentcmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        insertcommentcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        insertcommentcmd.CommandText = "insert into comments Values (@commentname, @email, @content, @date, @productid)";

        insertcommentcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commentname", commentname.Text);
        insertcommentcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
        insertcommentcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content.Text);
        insertcommentcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
        insertcommentcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid", id);

        insertcommentcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger to see what is really doing this code?. Put a breakpoint on the foreach line then step by step follow the code and verify if the variables contain the expected values and the final ExecuteNonQuery is executed

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @Steve Yes I tried it and realized the codes inside foreach loop don't work. but I can not understand why

Comment: @marc_s Ok I will check it out. thanks for your mention.

Comment: set a breakpoint at insertcommentcmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); and then check the value of insertcommentcmd.CommandText.